# terraform show returning 4 json objects

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

> **What specific syntax must be changed below in order for the terraform cli to return only one `json` object describing state instead of 4 `json` objects?**

The command we are currently running is:

```
terraform show --json
```

The results we get from the above command include 4 `json` objects as follows:

```
2021-11-24T16:32:19.181-0800 [INFO]  Terraform version: 1.0.8
2021-11-24T16:32:19.181-0800 [INFO]  Go runtime version: go1.16.4
2021-11-24T16:32:19.181-0800 [INFO]  CLI args: []string{"terraform", "show", "--json"}
2021-11-24T16:32:19.193-0800 [INFO]  CLI command args: []string{"show", "--json"}
GET /containerName/my.tfstate HTTP/1.1
Host: myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net
User-Agent: Terraform/1.0.8
X-Ms-Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:19 GMT
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09
Accept-Encoding: gzip
2021-11-24T16:32:20.752-0800 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Response for https://myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/my.tfstate:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 22852
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Md5: someHashCode==
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:19 GMT
Etag: "someHexTag"
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:11:57 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Ms-Blob-Type: BlockBlob
X-Ms-Creation-Time: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:02:50 GMT
X-Ms-Lease-State: available
X-Ms-Lease-Status: unlocked
X-Ms-Request-Id: another-request-id
X-Ms-Server-Encrypted: true
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09

{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.0.8",
  "serial": 1,
  "lineage": "...",
  "outputs": { ... },
  "resources": [ ... ]
}
2021-11-24T16:32:20.754-0800 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state lock for workspace "default"
2021-11-24T16:32:20.754-0800 [TRACE] backend/local: reading remote state for workspace "default"
2021-11-24T16:32:20.754-0800 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Request:
GET /containerName/my.tfstate HTTP/1.1
Host: myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net
User-Agent: Terraform/1.0.8
X-Ms-Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:20 GMT
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09
Accept-Encoding: gzip
2021-11-24T16:32:20.910-0800 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Response for https://myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/my.tfstate:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 22852
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Md5: someHashCode==
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:19 GMT
Etag: "someHexTag"
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:11:57 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Ms-Blob-Type: BlockBlob
X-Ms-Creation-Time: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:02:50 GMT
X-Ms-Lease-State: available
X-Ms-Lease-Status: unlocked
X-Ms-Request-Id: some-request-id
X-Ms-Server-Encrypted: true
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09

{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.0.8",
  "serial": 1,
  "lineage": "...",
  "outputs": { ... },
  "resources": [ ... ]
}
2021-11-24T16:32:20.925-0800 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "Applications"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.017-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "Applications"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "App Role Assignments"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "App Role Assignments"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "ConditionalAccess"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "ConditionalAccess"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "Directory Roles"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "Directory Roles"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "Domains"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "Domains"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "Groups"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "Groups"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "Invitations"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "Invitations"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "Service Principals"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "Service Principals"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.019-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Resources for "Users"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.019-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: 2021/11/24 16:32:21 [DEBUG] Registering Data Sources for "Users"..: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.018-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.021-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azuread_v2.6.0_x5.exe: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.020-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.162-0800 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-11-24T16:32:21.332-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5.exe: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.332-0800
2021-11-24T16:32:21.579-0800 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-11-24T16:32:21.657-0800 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-http_v2.1.0_x5.exe: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2021-11-24T16:32:21.656-0800

GET /containerName/my.tfstate HTTP/1.1
Host: myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net
User-Agent: Terraform/1.0.8
X-Ms-Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:21 GMT
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09
Accept-Encoding: gzip
2021-11-24T16:32:22.288-0800 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Response for https://myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/my.tfstate:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 22852
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Md5: someHashCode==
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:21 GMT
Etag: "someHexTag"
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:11:57 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Ms-Blob-Type: BlockBlob
X-Ms-Creation-Time: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:02:50 GMT
X-Ms-Lease-State: available
X-Ms-Lease-Status: unlocked
X-Ms-Request-Id: a-third-request-id
X-Ms-Server-Encrypted: true
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09

{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.0.8",
  "serial": 1,
  "lineage": "...",
  "outputs": { ... },
  "resources": [ ... ]
}

2021-11-24T16:32:22.290-0800 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Request:
GET /containerName/my.tfstate HTTP/1.1
Host: myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net
User-Agent: Terraform/1.0.8
X-Ms-Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:22 GMT
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09
Accept-Encoding: gzip
2021-11-24T16:32:22.462-0800 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Response for https://myStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/my.tfstate:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 22852
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Md5: someHashCode==
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 25 Nov 2021 00:32:21 GMT
Etag: "someHexTag"
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:11:57 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
X-Ms-Blob-Type: BlockBlob
X-Ms-Creation-Time: Tue, 23 Nov 2021 23:02:50 GMT
X-Ms-Lease-State: available
X-Ms-Lease-Status: unlocked
X-Ms-Request-Id: a-4th-request-id
X-Ms-Server-Encrypted: true
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09

{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.0.8",
  "serial": 1,
  "lineage": "...",
  "outputs": { ... },
  "resources": [ ... ]
}
```

> **What specifically do we have to change in order to receive one single `json` object in response which summarizes the state within that one single `json` object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard `terraform show --json` output. I suspect that you set [TF_LOG](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/debugging.html) to `DEBUG` or `INFO`. Thus you have to change that env variable to normal value. For example, if you run it in `bash` on linux you can change it in one line as follows:

```
TF_LOG=ERROR terraform show --json
```

Alternatively, in an os-agnostic language like Python, you would use two different lines to first set `TF_LOG=ERROR` on one line using `os.environ` and then run a shell command on a second line to run `terraform show --json` using something like `subprocess.popen`.  Remembering of course to re-set `TF_LOG` afterwards to whatever the user has as its default.

Comment: Why are you putting `TF_LOG=ERROR` on the same line as `terraform show --json` ?  Aren't those two different commands?

Comment: @CodeMed It just set the value of `TF_LOG` to `ERROR`. The point is that you somewhere set it to `DEBUG`. It could be your environment variable. You have to find where are you setting it, and change it to standard value. Otherwise, you get these detailed output from the command.

Comment: Yeah,  I got that.  So to use your suggestion, I set `TF_LOG=ERROR` in the line in our script right above the `terraform show --json` command, and then we set `TF_LOG=DEBUG` again right after the `terraform show --json` line.  ...  I am just saying that another reader of your answer in the future might not know to put it on two separate lines.  ...  Putting it on one single line as your answer shows causes an error that is resolved by splitting it on two separate lines.

Comment: @CodeMed This is one line, not two separate ones. I use `bash` on linux to run it. I can update the answer to clarify that. Thanks for pointing it out.